# Selenium / TestNG maven test schedule / run on GitLab runner

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, gitlab-ci-runner

I have my Selenium TestNG suites in GitLab. They currently use Maven. Instead of setting up Jenkins for scheduling mvn test, I want to achieve this on my gitlab using runners. But I do not know where to start or how to achieve this. Has anyone tried this? if yes can someone share detailed test steps? Thanks.

Comment: Vikas : can you please see if this blog post helps http://pragma-int.blogspot.in/2015/11/gitlab-ci-and-maven.html

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan This actually helps. Thanks a lot